# Green-shaded suggestion for using string resources in Android Studio editor doesn't stick over source file reopen

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Using Android Studio 2.3.3. Trying to replace hard-coded strings with references to string resources. In my activity code, if I left-click the following line, which has the string shaded green:

```
String text = "My text";
```

The editor will change the line to:

```
String text = getResource().getString(R.id.my_text);
```

which is exactly what I want to happen. However, if I close the file and reopen it, the editor reverts back to the original hard-coded string. I've tried Save, Save All, do a build, even manually type in the new code, but this keeps happening.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't actually revert your string to the hard-coded one. Android Studio actually shows you like that to help you remember what's the actual value of the String.

**EDIT:**

If you want to disable the feature, open preferences menu and navigate to `Editor > General > Code Folding`. You will see a lot of options to enable/disable code folding. The one you're looking for is `Android String References`. Just uncheck it and you'll be fine.

[image: Android Studio preferences panel]

Comment: Is there any way to disable that? I'd rather see the code the way i want it.

Comment: Yes, there is. The name of this feature is code folding. I updated my answer to include instructions on how to disable it.